# Парсинг XML .Анализ и запись массива в файл в файл

Tags: xml, парсер, ruby

Есть кусок кода на Ruby, он парсит с XML названия родителей(должен по крайней мере), так как какие-то данные в переменной names_list есть, а дальше нужно это записать в файл. В программировании не так давно, теорию знаю, как должно работать тоже, но сделать один хрен не могу. Прошу помощи, но только не так "на, работает", а с объяснением,  как можно более подробным. Спасибо.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
url = 'https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/592be1b73b99e296423fc048/592be1b73b99e296423fc05b/d827820d908d78b8db713483a306ef2d/mddrive.xml'

names_list = Array.new

doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))

parent = doc.at('//param').parent

p_parents = doc.xpath('//param')
p_parents.each do |node|
    names_list.push node.attr('name')
end

 File.open('results_for_task1.txt', 'w+') do |i|

    i.puts(names_list)
 end
```

Comment: Что именно сейчас не работает?

Comment: Cейчас уже переделал немного, и чуть лучше понял задачу) В общем мне нужно записать в файл имена всех узлов, которые имеют наследников. В данный момент я просто получаю имена ВСЕХ узлов. То есть нужно каким-то образом отобрать и записать только те узлы, которые имеют наследников, как-то так)  Насколько я понял, это должно быть написано в этой строке        "p_parents = doc.xpath('//param')"